# cfoutput group prices

Tags: sql, join, coldfusion

i want to group prices according to products id, like here: http://s44.radikal.ru/i106/1108/57/33380d0557f4.jpg but i can't group them properly, there are must be one product and few prices, rather than same products and different prices for each. so far with the help of Scott Stroz, i have wrote the code:

the query:

```
<cfquery name="get_products" datasource="#dsn3#">
    SELECT DISTINCT P.PRODUCT_ID,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,PR.PRICE
    FROM PRODUCT P
        JOIN PRICE_STANDART PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID
        JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
    WHERE P.IS_SALES=1 AND P.IS_PURCHASE=1 AND P.IS_INTERNET=1 AND PS.PURCHASESALES=1 AND PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1 
    <cfif len(trim(attributes.product_cat)) and len(attributes.product_code)>AND P.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '#attributes.product_code#%'</cfif>         
    <cfif isdefined('attributes.product_id') and len(attributes.product_id)>AND P.PRODUCT_ID=#attributes.product_id#</cfif>
    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID,PR.PRICE,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY
    ORDER BY PR.PRICE DESC
</cfquery>
```

and the table:

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="color-border" width="100%">
    <tr class="color-header">
        <td width="30" class="header_bold">No</td>
        <td><b>Ürün</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Liste fiyatı</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 1</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 2</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 3</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 4</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="25">Para</td>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="get_products" startrow="#attributes.startrow#" maxrows="#attributes.maxrows#" group="product_id">
        <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row">
            <td>#currentrow#</td>   
            <td>#product_name#</td>
            <cfoutput group="price"><td>#tlformat(price,2)#</td></cfoutput>
            <td align="center">#MONEY#</td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
```

thank you all guys for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a query that looks like this:

```
product_id, product_name, price
1, 'test', 100
1, 'test', 200
1, 'test', 300
2, 'test2', 100
2, 'test2', 200
2, 'test2', 300
```

The following code would group by product id and output each individual price

```
<cfoutput query="get_products" group="product_id">
    #product_name#
    Prices:
    <cfoutput>
        #price#<br>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Now, the group by in sql has nothing to do with coldfusions group in cfoutput. It's a convinience method to loop out unique rows. So when coldfusion sees two identical "product_id" it will run the nested cfoutput loop.

You can do this for as many levels you want, but in your case there only seems to be two.

Comment: thank you, but the real mistake was ORDER BY :) i should have ordered it by product_name ))

Comment: Just note `cfoutput group` relies on the results being sorted. If they are *not* sorted properly the output will be incorrect. So if you are grouping by `product_id` then `price`, the query must also be ordered by `product_id` and `price`.

Comment: @Leigh almost in all the sql questions u help me )) thank you very much, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Yah, forogot to mention that in my answer. By the way, DISTINCT seems unessecary when doing group by.