# order by in joined tables

Tags: sql, join, coldfusion, sql-order-by

i want to order the second joined table according to price, to exaplain it more clear i will add a screenshot: http://s42.radikal.ru/i098/1108/87/66f19d915bbc.jpg the second table displays the prices: bayi 1, bayi 2, bayi 3, bayi 4 and liste fiyati, i want to rearrange em in another order starting from liste fiyati and ending on bayi 1. here is my query:

```
<cfquery name="get_products" datasource="#dsn3#">
    SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,PR.PRICE,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK
    FROM PRODUCT P
        JOIN PRICE_STANDART PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID
        JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
        JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.GET_STOCK_LAST GSL ON P.PRODUCT_ID = GSL.PRODUCT_ID
    WHERE P.IS_SALES=1 AND P.IS_INTERNET=1 AND PS.PURCHASESALES=1 AND PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1
    AND PR.STARTDATE <= #now()# AND (PR.FINISHDATE >= #now()# OR PR.FINISHDATE IS NULL)
    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID,PR.PRICE,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK
    ORDER BY PS.PRICE DESC
</cfquery>
```

and the table:

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="color-border" width="100%">
    <tr class="color-header">
        <td><b>Ürün</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80"><b>Marka</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="35"><b>Stok</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="35"><b>Yoldaki Stok</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 4</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 3</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 2</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Bayı 1</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="80">Liste fiyatı</td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="25">Para</td>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="get_products" startrow="#attributes.startrow#" maxrows="#attributes.maxrows#" group="product_id">
        <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row"> 
            <td>#product_name#</td>
            <td align="center"><cfif len(brand_list)>#get_brands.brand_name[listfind(brand_list,brand_id,',')]#</cfif></td>
            <td align="center">#PRODUCT_STOCK#</td>
            <td align="center">#purchase_order_stock#</td>
            <cfoutput><td align="center">#tlformat(price,2)#</td></cfoutput>
            <td align="center">#MONEY#</td>
        </tr>
    <cfset toplam_stock = toplam_stock+product_stock>
    <cfset toplam_order_stock = toplam_order_stock+purchase_order_stock>
    </cfoutput>
    <tr class="color-header">
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td align="center"><cfoutput>#toplam_stock#</cfoutput></td>
        <td align="center"><cfoutput>#toplam_order_stock#</cfoutput></td>
        <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

btw, the price i want to order is PRICE PR not the PRICE_STANDART PS, and thank you all for help!

Comment: actually i have the same question as here: http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/821529-order-join-column but i didnt understand how can i adapt it to my query... :(

Comment: Im beginning to think you are trying to use 1 query to answer two different questions on your screen. Eg, each table may need its own query.

Comment: for those who gave me minus: please, if you don't know sql it doesnt mean i didn't explain my problem clear, as you can see, Dan Short understood my problem and gave me the right answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add both ORDER BY statements:

```
ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_ID, PS.PRICE DESC
```

With ColdFusion grouping, make sure that you *always* sort by what you want to group by first, then you can sort by whatever you need inside the group.

Comment: THAT IS THE RIGHT ANSWER! Thank you DAN!

Comment: @user775917 - Um.. I thought we just covered this issue ;) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066002/cfoutput-group-prices/7066440#comment-8454307

Comment: @Leigh yeah )) i also thought we covered this issue, but sometimes im neglectful and don't see the mistakes, especially in a new topics...

Answer (score 0):

But then change the

```
ORDER BY PS.PRICE DESC
```

to

```
 ORDER BY PR.PRICE DESC
```

Surely?

Comment: no, it will brake group by product_id in the table, i tried it before )) please, try to look carefully, what im trying to do is different from you assumption, this is inside the ouput that is grouped by product_id, i want to change its order: `<cfoutput><td align="center">#tlformat(price,2)#</td></cfoutput>`

Comment: I clearly need more caffine then, as your picture didnt assist in making it clearer. Only way I can then see would be to then query the result of that and sort it by the field you actually want it sorted by.

Comment: i dont know how to make it more clear )) these 5 different prices are looped horizontally, not vertically, and these 5 different prices i want to order in another way. at the same time, the price_standart ps is not displayed at all in the table, it is added just for defining some values and ordering the table vertically by price, but the price pr is displayed horizontally by these 5 different prices...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you need to include all the cols from the GROUP BY in your ORDER BY statement *first*, and then add any other columns that you want to order by within those groupings.

But I'm afraid to say yor question isn't terribly clear.

-- 
Adam

Comment: nope, it will order the table vertically, i want to order it horizontally in every line

Comment: Sorry, don't follow.  Can you provide some sample data of the "desired results" and highlight what you want compared to what we're suggesting?

-- 
Adam

Comment: have a look at the screenshot above, hope it will enlighten you :)

Comment: Hmmm.  Yes, thanks, I saw that.  And then I offered an answer to your question.  And then I was somehow missing the point.  So then I asked for further clarification.

I think the disconnect is your notion of "ordering horizontally". In the context of ordering records, it's not particularly clear what you mean (well at least to me!).

If you could do what I asked, it would make things go a lot more smoothly, I think.

-- 
Adam

Comment: Like Adam, I think really we need a simplified this is what I get, from the results of the db[show some fake results], I want to display those results like [example using faked results]. We can then help.

Comment: on the screenshot, the values of first product: 4.820,00 - 5.121,00 - 5.422,00 - 6.025,00 - 12.049,00 i want to see them like: 12.049,00 - 6.025,00 - 5.422,00 - 5.121,00 - 4.820,00 and in this way for every product